# Bash - why doesn't this condition do what I think it should do?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

This is basically my first script in bash so I'm probably missing something really simple.

I don't understand why `"$(pgrep firefox)"` appears to return something even if firefox is not running.

The script should always keep a firefox instance running.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
        if [ -z "$(pgrep firefox)" ]
                then
                        echo "firefox not running. Starting now..."
                        firefox
        fi
done
```

The really weird thing is if I type this at the bash command prompt it works as expected

```
if [ -z "$(pgrep firefox)" ];  then echo "not running"; fi
```

Comment: you realise that your command prompt test has the logic reversed ("running" v "not running")?  also, no need for the ";" after true (don't think it would hurt though).

Comment: I meant 'not running'. Updated, thanks!

Comment: That is a very busy script. You might want to sleep for a few seconds inside the while loop.

Comment: @glenn jackman I thought about it too, but won't executing 'firefox' block execution until firefox is closed? Would get busy only if FF was running prior to executing the script. This situation shouldn't exist in the context I'll use it. But I think I'll put a sleep in the else clause. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried printing out the result of `$(pgrep firefox)` to see what is being returned?

By the way, you don't need to compare strings here. `pgrep` returns true if a process is found and false otherwise, so you can do this:

```
if ! pgrep firefox
then
    echo firefox not running
fi
```

Comment: Running  `echo $(pgrep firefox)` displays the pid if ff is running or nothing if it doesn't

Comment: Ok. I put your example in a blank new script and tested. If firefox is not running I get the pid of the actual script. If FF IS running I get 2 PIDs, one for ff and one for the script. If I run from the command prompt it works as expected. Doesn't make sense!

Comment: ah, it does!  you're seeing the pid for the script

Comment: what's the script called?  are you sure the script isn't seeing itself?!  pgrep takes a regexp.

Comment: @Bogdan does your script have "firefox" in it's name? That must be why pgrep is picking it up. Call it something else.

Comment: to be completely clear - pgrep will filter itself (the pgrep process) from any match, but it's not going to filter the calling script if that matches too.

Comment: Of course this is it. Soooo stupid of me! it was named "start-firefox" of course :))

Comment: Why are you using pgrep at all?  Why not just do: "while true; do firefox; done" ?

Comment: @William Pursell, I want to make sure only one instance is run, even if the script is called twice form other places.